# How could you do a Get Random to get images from a url?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, url, android-imageview

I am making an application and I want one of the Fragments to have an ImageView and the image to be taken from a URL that connects to my VPS. I would like you to tell me how can I take a random url from the img folder of the url `https://imagerandom.com/img` (that url is an example) and project it to ImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

If you already have a bunch of images you can follow below steps:-

1)first import the all images in the file/code.

2)then store their names in the array or list of string/integer depending upon the name type.

3)then uses the random function to generate index of list/array.

4)then store the random index in some variable and you can use that to have a random images.

### Method 2

On internet a lot of websites are available for generating random pictures

I used "picsum" and help me a lot in various web application for testing

### Link for the site:-

https://picsum.photos/

hope you gonna love it !!

Comment: Thank you very much friend, that information was useful to me thank you very much and I wish you luck

Comment: I still can't believe how much this worked like a charm to help me populate some random posts. Thank you, my brother! ;-D